# Is it possible to know the number of unread Slack messages a user has with the Slack API?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm building a messaging integration with Slack and a client. I need to show the badges on the corresponding conversations when the users logs in to the client to show the client how many unread messages it has.

I know that the `channels.history` method had the **unreads** parameter which would return as part of the response the amount of unread messages according to the user token, but that method is deprecated and my app is too new to use it.

I'm using the `conversations.history` now to retrieve the messages which is what slack suggest to use instead of the deprecated method `channel.history`, but this new method doesn't have that parameter and doesn't show any info regarding the amount of unread messages in the conversation.

As my app is a new one and not a classic one, I cannot use the RTM API.

I'm also subscribed to the message events so that I know when a new message was posted.

My issue is that I need to know how many new messages were sent to the user while he was not logged in.

Is there any way to get that info?

Comment: I would also like to know this. In my searching it sounds like they don’t provide anything like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unread count is in `conversations.info` method, not in `conversations.history`. There in `unread_count` and `unread_count_display` property in reponse. Documentation is [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info).

Comment: Note: documentation of `conversations.info` indicates that _Some fields in the response, like `unread_count` and `unread_count_display`, are included for DM conversations only._ However, send the `unreads` parameter to `conversations.history` and you will get `unread_count_display` in the response, for channels and DMs. This works today: `curl -s "https://slack.com/api/conversations.history?token=[TOKEN]&channel=[CHANNEL-or-DM]&limit=1&unreads=true&pretty=1"`. However, it's not in their doc, so it might stop working at anytime...

Answer (score 1):

As of somewhere this year (2023), the `unreads` flag stopped working (it is not in the response anymore).

I couldn't find a reliable way to get if a channel is read or not, so I asked their support team, and as far as they know, there is no way today to get if a channel is read or not...

I wish there was an event from their API that could at least inform when a message is read, so I could use Redis or another memory cache platform to store new messages and remove them on callback.